# duckdb unnest keep empty rows

Tags: sql, duckdb

What is the syntax to unnest the following table `my_table` in duckdb

| id | x |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:4}] |

into the following

| id | x |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | {a:1,b:2} |
| 2 | {a:3,b:4} |

The query `select unnest(x) from mytable;` simply removes the empty row. A query like
`select id, val from mytable left join unnest(x) as val on true;` is not possible in duckdb. I also tried in combination with coalesce for example.

Comment: What's the datatype of column `x`

Comment: this would be 'struct(struct("a varchar, b varchar))[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually add the rows where `x` is a `null` value using `union all`:

```
select id, unnest(x)
from mytable
union all
select id, null
from mytable
where x is null
order by id
```

(The `order by` clause is optional.)

Comment: thanks, came up with the same solution, seems that no "one-liner" exists..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select id, unnest(x) from mytable
```

Comment: does not work unfortunately.

Comment: what's the output? I don't have access to any duckdb platform.

Comment: Try https://shell.duckdb.org/